How to find duplicate values in MySQL in a column with data type array<string>
I have a columnn named pay_type with data_type : array string and I would like to query for when this column has duplicate values.
Example:
Table_Name: Finance
Columns: customer_id,pay_type

How can I query in mysql to return rows 1 and 3 which have duplicated values in their pay_type ? 

You might want to check the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Please post your sample table & data query @Kadodo14

@Kadodo14 what is data type of pay_type column ?

@Kadodo14 Please accept the answer .... and close the ticket

You can use JSON_TABLE() to turn the array elements into rows:
WITH finance (customer_id, pay_type) AS (
    VALUES
        ROW(1, '["Check","Check"]'),
        ROW(2, '["Cash"]'),
        ROW(3, '["Cash","Cash"]')
)
SELECT f.customer_id, t.pay_type
FROM finance f
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(pay_type, '$[*]' COLUMNS ( pay_type VARCHAR(20) PATH '$' )) t
GROUP BY f.customer_id, t.pay_type
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

Outputs:



customer_id
pay_type




1
Check


3
Cash



Here's a db<>fiddle.

wow, great .... @user1191247
I learn something today ...

Hi, @user1191247
Sometimes observe data duplication is happening:  https://dbfiddle.uk/Fl7Te0uU

@ArtBindu Good spot. That could be worked around but not sure how OP is planning to use the query. I think your regex will see ["Cash","Check"] as a dupe.

I have added an alternative solution. Trying to fixed through regex matching.
drop table if exists t1;
CREATE TABLE t1 (customer_id int not null primary key, pay_type JSON);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1, '["Check", "Check"]');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(2, '["Cash"]');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(3, '["Cash", "Cash"]');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(4, '["Cash", "Check", "Cash"]');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(5, '["Check", "Cash", "Cash"]');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(6, '["Check", "Cash", "Cash", "Check"]');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(7, '["Check"]');

-- Update this according to distinct pay_type
set @pay_types_regex = '(Cash|Check)';
select *  from t1 where 
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(cast(pay_type as char(255)), @pay_types_regex, 1, 2) is not NULL;


Sample Code: https://dbfiddle.uk/RkkMsrUV
